# Particle system DontDestroyOnLoad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system, unity3d-2dtools

What I'm after in my game is when a collision happens with the player and a planet, for the player to disappear, leaving behind an explosion effect in the form of a particle system. Just afterwards (maybe half a second) I want the "game over" scene to appear in its place. Here's what I have so far:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col) {
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "enemyPlanet") {
        Instantiate (explosion, thingToMove.transform.position, thingToMove.transform.rotation);
        ui.gameOverActivated ();
        Destroy (gameObject);
        am.rocketBang.Play();
        Application.LoadLevel ("gameOverScene2");
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the particles appear but don't move as they should like an explosion. I guess that's either because the game over scene is loading or because its position is the player (`thingToMove`) which is being destroyed.

I tried this:

```
public void Awake() {
    DontDestroyOnLoad (transform.gameObject);
}
```

But the same thing happens. If it's because the player is being destroyed, how would I make it be in the place of the player at the time of it being destroyed?

I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Invoke` method to call the game over after a specified delay.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col) {
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "enemyPlanet") {
        Instantiate (explosion, thingToMove.transform.position, thingToMove.transform.rotation);
        ui.gameOverActivated ();
        am.rocketBang.Play();
        Invoke( "over", 2.0f );

    }
}

void over(){
    Destroy (gameObject);
    Application.LoadLevel ("gameOverScene2");
}
```

Comment: Spot on. Thank you very much.